# RSpec controller lookup

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to define a RSpec test for a controller named `FindWithSameDirectorController`.
I got a `ActionController::RoutingError. No route matches {:id => 1, :controller => 'find_with_same_director', : action => 'show'}`.
The controller name doesn't match the controller that i define.
How does rspec determines this name ? Is it possible to change it ?
Thx
Bertrand

Comment: I'm not 100% sure where the problem lies. Please add your `routes.rb` and your controller spec file. I have added a preliminary answer, but I need more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your spec propably looks like this:

```
describe FindWithSameDirectorController do
  it { should route(:get, '/find_with_same_director/1').to action: 'show', id: 1 }
end
```

but in your `config/routes.rb` you have either missing a line like

```
resources :find_with_same_director
```

(**or** this resource is overwritten by another route specification).